# how do I get my relieving letter in this situation?

Tags: management, india, relieving-letter

I quit my job in the month of march (unofficially) due to personal reasons and I was ready to serve my notice period but my manager told me that if I quit at that particular time the attrition rate would go high and there are many more people in line who are serving their notice period so he would process it officially after a month or so which includes the formal procedure to exit. I trusted him thinking he would call me but he never did.

He kept dodging me saying it's taking time and in the month of October 27th 2014 I received a message from the hr team saying my separation is processed which I thought was good and my manager has taken care of it.

After this on 27th Dec 2014 I received another text saying my F & F (full and final settlement) is processed. So I check my mail and to my shock I received a mail from the F & F team saying I have to pay dues of 11,000. So that means they haven't processed my relieving days properly which is technically 30days.

Note I was ready to serve my notice period in the month of March which they did not agree to. It's only because of their advice I left thinking they would do it because they had the controls. Now I need the relieving letter which every other company is asking if I have it and I don't. When I speak to my managers about it they say I have to pay the dues to get my relieving letter or they never bother to get back to me on the issue. Why should I pay it when it wasn't my fault? What should I do in this case?

Comment: aw bleh, I just made a mayor edit to improve readability :(

Comment: @Martijn: sorry, we conflicted...

Comment: i do not have any official assurances like on email from the manager saying he would process it later.

Answer (score 1):

> my manager told me that if I quit at that particular time the attrition rate would go high and there are many more people in line who are serving their notice period so he would process it officially after a month or so which includes the formal procedure to exit.

I hope you got this in writing, otherwise you're fighting an uphill battle.

I would advise you attempt to reach the manager that you discussed this with, and see what they can do. Your next best step after that is to try and convince HR.

Unfortunately in this case, there's not much that you can do directly. If they are unwilling to listen or make changes, then you need to reach out to your union manager or a lawyer.